# How i can replace data in data (JSRender)

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I have sent request to get Data from API
So data return like

[Check here to see Data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkBhA.png)

So i want to replace data in "launchUrl" such playerName

This is my code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ $luckyStreakLobbyAPI }}",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        Data: {
            Open: true,
            GameTypes: [],
            Currencies: []
        }
    },
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + "ey"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>");
        var data = data.data.games,
        tmpl = $.templates('#luckyStreakTables'),
        html = tmpl.render(data);
        console.log(data);
        $('.row.tables').html($('#luckyStreakTables').render(data));
    }
});
```

So data from api will return in "success: function(**data**)"
How i can replace data in **data.data.games.launchUrl**

Comment: are u going to replace `data.data.games.launchUrl` in data ?

Comment: @pandian_Snkl I need to replace it but how ?